# How can i update my html page using LoadableDetachableModel?

Tags: sorting, wicket

I'm trying to have just a simple html page which loads a small amount of data into a table. This works fine using the code i have now. Now, i'd like it to sort on for instance, the namelink tab ( which is the headliner basically for where the names come in). But i can't figure out how to do it. The sorting function i'm just doing in the SQL and once i get one piece to start working, i should be able to figure out the massive SQL sentence and all the other functions to work perfect, just need to get this started.
This is my code:

```
public class SimpleView extends SimpleViewPage {

IModel model;

public SimpleView() {
    model = new LoadableDetachableModel() {

        @Override
        protected Object load() {
            PersonService pM = new PersonService();
            return pM.getAllPersons(new OrderByOption());
        }
    };

    add(new ListView("persons", model) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            Person person = (Person) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", person.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("birthdate", person.getBirthdate()));
            item.add(new Label("phone", person.getPhone()));
        }
    });

    add(new Label("size", "Number of people: " + getPersons().size()));
    add(new Link("namelink") {

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            ;
        }
    });
    add(new Link("datelink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
        }
    });
    add(new Link("phonelink") {

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope someone can help me! And i'm fairly new to programming in general, so an example would be so helpful including theory, if possible :) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wicket MyBatis Want to sort a row but can't update it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443397/wicket-mybatis-want-to-sort-a-row-but-cant-update-it)

Comment: Well the sorting happens in the SQL, i just want the row's to update as i Click it. And i'm not sure i understand your answer on the other one.

Comment: When you want to refresh the page? After clicking one of the namelink/datelink/phonelink?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will show you how to implement this via ajax (not to reload whole page, but only `ListView`).

To update `ListView` via ajax you must put it on the `WebMarkupContainer` (this is wicket requirements). Also you must use `AjaxLink` instead of just 'Link'.

```java
public class SimpleView extends SimpleViewPage
{

    //container which contains ListView.
    private WebMarkupContainer container;

    //I don't know your OrderByOption implementation, but I'd rather make it enumeration(it could be everywhere you want):
    public static enum OrderByOption

    {
        NO_ORDER, NAME, DATE, PHONE;
    }

    //so you must store any field that represents current store, to update your model properly.
    private OrderByOption currentOrder = OrderByOption.NO_ORDER;

    public SimpleView ()
    {

        //generics added for convenience
        Imodel<List<Person>> model = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Person>> ()
        {

            @Override
            protected Object load ()
            {
                PersonService pM = new PersonService ();
                //as I understand sorting logic at SQL-side, so, you must return lists with order according to currentOrder parameter 
                return pM.getAllPersons ( currentOrder );
            }
        };

        container = new WebMarkupContainer ( "listViewContainer" );
        //to update any component via ajax, you must set its outputmarkupid flag to true
        container.setOutputMarkupId ( true );

        container.add ( new ListView<Person> ( "persons", model )
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem ( ListItem<Person> item )
            {
                Person person = item.getModelObject ();
                item.add ( new Label ( "name", person.getName () ) );
                item.add ( new Label ( "birthdate", person.getBirthdate () ) );
                item.add ( new Label ( "phone", person.getPhone () ) );
            }
        } );

        add ( new Label ( "size", "Number of people: " + getPersons ().size () ) );

        add ( new AjaxLink ( "nameLink" )
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( AjaxRequestTarget target )
            {
                currentOrder = OrderByOption.NAME;
                target.add ( container );
            }
        } );
        add ( new AjaxLink ( "datelink" )
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( AjaxRequestTarget target )
            {
                currentOrder = OrderByOption.DATE;
                target.add ( container );
            }
        } );
        add ( new AjaxLink ( "phonelink" )
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( AjaxRequestTarget target )
            {
                currentOrder = OrderByOption.PHONE;
                target.add ( container );
            }
        } );
        add ( container );
    }
}
```

You also need to update your html file to wrap your `ListView`:

```html
...
    <div wicket:id="listViewContainer">
        <div wicket:id="persons">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

If you do your sorting right, then your `ListView` will be properly updated.
If you are not familiar with enumerations (like OrderByOption I've implemented), then you may use any type you want, for examlpe - int (1 - for name sorting, 2 - for dat, etc.). You must take into account, that you must somehow say your model what sorting to fetch now (when panel is updated), so one of the approach to achive this - is to store an global field like `currentOrder`.

Hope this helps.